# Generate urls for video,audio and image files in django

Tags: django, file, media

I am developing a website where user can upload their pictures,audios and videos.All users can see files uploaded by other users.Now I don't want any user to download files uploaded by other users.How can I securely display files on a webpage without allowing any user to download any files?

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest managing media request through a view.

```
@login_required
def getmedia(request, media_id):
    media = get_object_or_404(Media, pk=media_id)
    if media.owner != request.user:
        #Handle user not owning the media
        HttpResposeRedirect("/404")
    # Handle users owning the media
```

Comment: I want to do something like this.Suppose my file is at "/site_media/static/images/myimg.jpg" but I want the url to be something like /kjashaJKSHA and my image is not downloadable.

Comment: Oh, I see. If you are going to display media to all the other users I don't think you can prevent them from downloading it through any conventional means.

Comment: I guess an alternative could be to generate 'previews' that all others users can see. Thumbnails for images, a few screen captures for videos, etc.

Answer (score 0):

You can't make it non-downloadable, because the web browser *must* download it to render the page, and once it's already been downloaded, the end-user can do whatever they like.

About the only thing you could do is wrap it completely in a Flash control (i.e. the movie would actually be a SWF file), but that *still* doesn't stop people from downloading it; it only makes what they download less useful.